# Luasocket - How to send/receive UDP broadcast messages?

Tags: networking, lua, udp, broadcast, luasocket

I've been trying to do this for a while. I tried following this http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/UDP-Broadcast-td3995269.html, but to no avail. I've successfully sent *unicast* messages between the client and server. I've confirmed my broadcast address is correct. The only other thing I can think of is sniffing my interface to make sure there's no network problems. I'm gonna get around to that tomorrow, but wanted to post this here to see if anyone might notice a stupid mistake.

Note: I'm running the client and the server on the same laptop.

**client**

```
local socket = require("socket")
local s_address, s_port = "192.168.1.135", 33333
local d_address, d_port = "192.168.1.255", 22222

udp = socket.udp()
assert(udp)
assert(udp:settimeout(1))
assert(udp:setoption('broadcast', true))
assert(udp:setoption('dontroute',true))
assert(udp:setsockname(s_address, s_port))

while true do
  tosend = string.format("client %s:%s", s_address, s_port)
  print(string.format('sending to %s:%s...', d_address, d_port))
  udp:sendto(tosend, d_address, d_port)

  data, msg = udp:receive()
  toprint = string.format("data = \"%s\"", data)
  print(toprint)
  socket.sleep(.5)
end
```

**server**

```
local socket = require("socket")
local s_address, s_port = "192.168.1.135", 11111
local p_address, p_port = "192.168.1.255", 22222

udp = socket.udp()
assert(udp)
assert(udp:setoption('broadcast', true))
assert(udp:setoption('dontroute',true))
assert(udp:settimeout(1))
assert(udp:setsockname(s_address, s_port))
assert(udp:setpeername(p_address, p_port))

while true do
  data = udp:receive()
  print(string.format('listening on %s:%s...', p_address, p_port))
  toprint = string.format("data = \"%s\"", data)
  print(toprint)
  if data then
    msg_back = "server received your message"
    udp:send(msg_back)
  end
  socket.sleep(.5)
end
```

**output**
Both sides continually print `data = "nil"`.

Comment: If you want to connect between two devices, why are you using broadcast, which is designed to interrupt _every_ host on the LAN. This seems to be a misuse of broadcast. Only use broadcast if you want to interrupt _every_ host, otherwise you should use unicast or multicast (for multiple hosts).

Comment: @RonMaupin I want to communicate to multiple hosts, but for now I'm testing with a single client and server (for simplicity).

Comment: Right, but multicast is what you should use for a group of multiple hosts. Broadcast is for _every_ host, and it is mostly misused, which is one reason the IPv6 doesn't have broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking to implement luasocket broadcast myself, and this was one of the few pages on the internet that even brought the topic up. In the end, between the luasocket API and some python code I was able to adapt, I found a solution that works for me:

```
local socket = require 'socket'
local HOME_ADDR = '192.168.0.1'
local SUBNET_PATTERN = '%d+%.%d+%.%d+%.'

local function get_own_address()
  local s = assert(socket.udp())
  assert(s:setpeername(HOME_ADDR, 80))
  local host = s:getsockname()
  s:close()
  return host
end

function broadcast(message, address, port)
  local broadcaster = assert(socket:udp())
  assert(broadcaster:setoption('broadcast', true))
  assert(broadcaster:setoption('dontroute', true))   -- do we need this?

  print(('Broadcasting %q to %s:%i'):format(message, address, port))
  assert(broadcaster:sendto(message, address, port))
  broadcaster:close()
end

function antiphony(message, timeout, call_port, response_port, response_mask)
  local message, timeout, mask = tostring(message), tonumber(timeout) or 1.5, response_mask or '*a'
  local send_port, recv_port = call_port or 10500, response_port or 10501
  local broadcast_address = get_own_address():match(SUBNET_PATTERN) .. '255'
  local listener = assert(socket.bind('*', recv_port, 64))
  local clients, responses, starttime = {}, {}

  listener:settimeout(0)
  broadcast(message, broadcast_address, send_port)
  starttime = socket.gettime()
  repeat clients[listener:accept() or false] = true
  until socket.gettime() - starttime > timeout

  for client in pairs(clients) do 
    if client then
      responses[client:getpeername()] = tostring(client:receive(mask))
      client:close()
    end
  end
  listener:close()

  return responses
end

function listen(response_callback, timeout, listen_port, reply_port)
  local recv_port, send_port = tonumber(listen_port) or 10500, tonumber(reply_port) or 10501
  local callback = response_callback or function()end
  local address = get_own_address():match(SUBNET_PATTERN) .. '255'
  local sleeper = socket.udp()

  sleeper:settimeout(timeout)
  sleeper:setsockname(address, recv_port)
  repeat
    local data, ip, port = sleeper:receivefrom(1024)
    if data then callback(ip, send_port, data) end
  until not data
end

function respond(message, data_handler) 
  return function(ip_addr, port, data)
    assert(ip_addr and port, ('Invalid address: %s:%s'):format(tostring(ip_addr), tostring(port)))
    local msg = tostring(type(data_handler) == 'function' and (data_handler(data, message) or messsage) or message)
    local sender = assert(socket.connect(ip_addr, port))
    assert(sender:send(msg))
    sender:close()
  end
end

--[[

-- Listener / Responder:
listen(respond('polo', print), 600) -- 10 minute timeout

-- Broadcaster / Receiever:
for address, response in pairs(antiphony('marco')) do 
  print(address, response) 
end

]]
```

Comment: Remember that broadcast interrupts _every_ host on the LAN to inspect the broadcast by sending it up the network stack to see if the host is interested in the broadcast, including things like routers, printers, etc. that simply are not interested in the broadcast. Most businesses today will reject an application that uses broadcast as it is simply not secure, creating a security risk, and wasting bandwidth on the LAN. IPv6 eliminated broadcast, so a broadcast application cannot be ported to IPv6. The modern way to do it in this century is to use multicast.

Comment: @RonMaupin : Yes, but if you have to discover an unknown number of embedded devices on a local subnet that are set up to respond to broadcast but don't have multicast capability and the only tool you have to do it with is lua, this is how to do it.